# Unable to terminate/ purge Azure Durable Function entirely

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have removed some functions from my code. But it seems that I keep receiving that those functions are not available despite the removal.

```
[2021-07-19T02:47:28.400Z] Activity function 'MainActTemp' does not exist.. InstanceId: . Function: MainActTemp. HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.5.0. SequenceNumber: 2.

[2021-07-19T02:47:29.387Z] The function 'MainSubtemp' doesn't exist, is disabled, or is not an orchestrator function. Additional info: The following are the known orchestrator functions: .. InstanceId: f3c412cd19e54926a9343f618d6f3083:0. Function: MainSubtemp. HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.5.0. SequenceNumber: 3.
```

I have the following code to terminate and purge all instances which I have ran and the result is 0 but I still receive the above message that those functions does not exist.

```
public static async Task<int> TerminateInstances(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
       [DurableClient]IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {
            // Query for all running instances
            OrchestrationStatusQueryResult result = await starter.GetStatusAsync(
                new OrchestrationStatusQueryCondition
                {
                    RuntimeStatus = new[]
                {
            OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending,
            OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running,
                }
                },
                CancellationToken.None);

            // Make a hash set to track all instances we got back
            var running = new HashSet<string>(result.DurableOrchestrationState.Select(s => s.InstanceId));
            int instanceCount = running.Count;

            // Send terminate commands to all instances in parallel
            var terminateTasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (string instanceId in running)
            {
                terminateTasks.Add(starter.TerminateAsync(instanceId, "None"));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(terminateTasks);

            // Wait for the orchestrations to actually terminate
            while (true)
            {
                // Query all "running" instances in parallel
                DurableOrchestrationStatus[] results = await Task.WhenAll(
                    running.Select(id => starter.GetStatusAsync(id)));

                foreach (DurableOrchestrationStatus status in results)
                {
                    // Remove any terminated or completed instances from the hashset
                    if (status != null &&
                        status.RuntimeStatus != OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending &&
                        status.RuntimeStatus != OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running)
                    {
                        running.Remove(status.InstanceId);
                    }
                }

                // We are done once the HashSet has no more items in it
                if (running.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Still waiting for some instances to complete
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }

            return instanceCount;
        }
```

I have also looked into my storage account's table and queue, they are empty. How can I do a clean up? Thank you!

---

**Solution Update**

`PurgeInstanceHistoryAsync` or the above purge function appears to only be able to remove the `<DurableTaskHubName>History` and `<DurableTaskHubName>Instances` tables. But queues and blob containers are not fully cleared, hence any function instance that was not gracefully terminated will causes the above issue.
The workaround is via the answer below by using a separate DurableTaskHub name and run once to ensure the desired behavior and you may clean up the all testhubname related resources in Azure Storage.

[image]

Comment: Follow up on this, I am having the same issue.  I cleaned up the history, instances tables and the large-messages blob.  But the job is still there, and right now it keep on failing because I deleted all the messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you may change name of your Azure Durable Function Hub by

**Updated**
The *host.json* metadata file contains logical container for durable storage resources related to bindings to a each function in Azure Function App.

**version 2 naming**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "HubName": "TaskHubV1"
    }
  }
}
```

after you changes if working well you need to find out where your storage location and can do manual clean up.

Comment: Hi @Turbot, thank you! It worked! Is it possible if you could edit your answer to mention the file name (host.json) for that change? Will mark it as correct afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: @chiaDev , updated with reference of `host.json`